# Ruby parse CSV file to print out the rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a file upload in my Rails application and I want to parse the CSV file assuming the upload went okay. You can see the comment below that indicates where I would like to read the rows of the CSV file. How can I do this? I used carrierwave for the file upload.

I mounted it as such

```
mount_uploader :file, LCFileUploader
```

Here is the code I currently have

```
require 'CSV'
class LCFilesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        authorize! :create, :lc_file
        @lc_file = LCFile.new
    end

    def create
        authorize! :create, :lc_file
        puts params
        @lc_file = LCFile.new(params[:lc_file])
        @lc_file.user_id = current_user.id
        if @lc_file.save

            #PARSE CSV HERE TO PRINT OUT THE ROWS OF THE CSV FILE
            CSV.foreach(@lc_file.file.path) do |row|
                puts row
            end

            redirect_to lc_path, :notice => 'New lc created!'
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
end
```

and I get this error:

```
undefined method `find_all_by_team_id' for #<Class:0x007fe14c40d848>
```

Comment: (question should be closed. error I had was unrelated to what was posted or asked in this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):

```
puts CSV.read(@lc_file.file.path)
```

or one row at a time:

```
CSV.foreach(@lc_file.file.path) do |row|
  puts row
end
```

Besides CSV generation there are a few more issues:

- the redirect will not work after you send send some output. But even if it did, the output would not be seen, since you're redirecting.
- the path you are redirecting to is incorrect (I believe that's why you get that error). I suppose you want something like `lcfiles_path` or `lcfile_path(@lc_file)`. Run `rake routes` (the same way you ran rails console) to see a list of all available routes.

Now if you still have issues, I suggest posting another question, as this one was mainly about CSV generation and that should be solved using the code I posted at the start of this answer.

Comment: That gave me a undefined method `find_all_by_team_id' for #<Class:0x007fe14c2c4658>

Comment: Does your upload actually work? If yes, how do you access the file? Did you replace the `file` I used with the mounted uploader column?

Comment: See update for how I mounted. Yes, the upload actually works. I'm not sure how to access the file. As of now, it saves when the upload is executed using the code above.

Comment: Can you say what's the output of `LCFile.last.file.path` if you run it from the rails console? (I assume you have at least one file uploaded)

Comment: sorry...but how do I do that? I'm on Mac using terminal to start my server

Comment: I suppose you start your server using `rails server`. Start another terminal, go to the project folder and type `rails console`. You can now access everything in the Rails environment. Try to execute the command I mentioned above.

Comment: LCFile Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "lc_files".* FROM "lc_files" ORDER BY "lc_files"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "/Users/Me/Folder/Folder/cs/Folder/public/uploads/lc/lc_file_.csv"

Comment: I have updated my answer to fix a few other issues. The CSV generation should work with the code I gave you, you can run `CSV.read(LCFile.last.file.path)` in the console and you will see an array with all the rows in that file - so I believe this question is answered.

Comment: Sorry about that. The code you gave me did work. The output was in the terminal, and I was looking for the output in the browser...WHOOPS! I think this question should be closed. The error was not related to anything I've asked about.

Comment: The error was not related to the question, but I believe what you actually asked was answered (and the answer helped find the error anyway). So you can accept it, or if you feel it should be closed you'll probably have to contact an admin.